# convert C to PHP

Tags: php, c

I found this C source here. But needed it in PHP. Don't know how to code. Simply asking for help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LENGTH 3
void print_binary(int n)
{
        int bit = 1<<LENGTH - 1;
        while ( bit ) {
        printf("%d", n & bit ? 1 : 0);
        bit >>= 1;
        }
        printf("\n");
}
int main(){
    int n = 1<<LENGTH, i; 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        print_binary(i);
}
```

Comment: C>PHP, it's kinda like moving garbage from one dumpster to another:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple conversion.

```
<?php
define('LENGTH', 3);

function print_binary($n)
{
    $bit = 1<<LENGTH - 1;
    while($bit)
    {
        echo $n & $bit ? 1 : 0;
        $bit >>= 1;
    }
    echo "\n";
}

$n = 1<<LENGTH;
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
    print_binary($i);
?>
```

Comment: @user2856734 I suppose you're luck I am feeling bored. you really should be trying this yourself.

Comment: @user2856734 I'm just wonder How you know you need it if you can't code?

Comment: thank you so much. I am not a coder but i do understand logics. Needed it for one of my projects.